# qgis-processing: possible to specify variable number of output layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

Qgis-processing advises that output layers are specified with syntax such as

```
##foo=output vector
```

The manual advises against manually loading output layers (in your script code) as QGIS will do this automatically based on the above code.

What if the number of output layers is not known until runtime?  Is there a way to do this besides loading them manually and specifying `##nomodeler`?

Comment: Not sure I follow you 100%, are you wanting to load all output files automatically regardless of how many there are? If so then you can use the `runandload` function. E.g. `processing.runandload("qgis:myAlgorithm",...)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.  Though if I use the call you suggest, how will processing know where those files are?  the syntax I quote in the question only allows me to tell QGIS where a fixed number of named outputs will reside.

Comment: Not much of an expert on this so can't comment much :). But once a process is complete, the file will be saved either in the location you set or in the `temp` folder. Regardless where, QGIS can still load the output. If you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/164195/edit) your question to include your script, I'm sure you will get the attention of potential answerers :)

Comment: There isn't a script yet.  But maybe a link to the docs I'm talking about will help add context to the discussion? https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html#communicating-with-the-user