# How to output multiple raster in QGIS processing scripts

Tags: qgis, raster, r, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I am writing a script in R for running in QGIS processing. The code is a oil spill classification algorithm and depending on the number of polygons which user inputs in the shapefile, output raster layers are to be produced, each containing the oil/water classification plot corresponding to each polygon in the shapefile. Since I do not know in advance how many polygons user is going to input, I cannot specify in the processing header like:

```
##out_plot_raster_1 = output raster
##out_plot_raster_2 = output raster
##out_plot_raster_3 = output raster
.
.
.
```

QGIS processing scripts support multiple raster input like:

```
## input_many_rasters = multiple raster
```

so it is logically inferred that same must be true for output also, but on trying:

```
## out_many_rasters = output multiple raster
```

I get an error and the script won't run at all.

Now, it is really important for me to be able to output multiple rasters at once so that user can get all the friendly options like "saving them to desired location" and "opening them in QGIS after the script run" which are automatically provided by the processing framework of QGIS. How do I do this? i.e. I want user to be able to enter, before the script run, the location to store all generated raster outputs and if he wants, the rasters must be opened in QGIS automatically after the execution is complete.
Please suggest me a way to do this.

Comment: This question has come up before ([possible to specify variable number of output layers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/164195/2856)) and has no answer. I had a quick look at the 2.18 [source code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/release-2_18/python/plugins/processing/script/ScriptAlgorithm.py) and can not see anything that suggests setting multiple outputs as a single param is possible.  It is however possible in QGIS 3x, but note the 3x "script" syntax is now completely different and much more complex (though much more flexible and powerful).

Comment: @Luke But QGIS 3.x, does not have a support for running R scripts in the processing >> toolbox menu. That was the reason I shifted to 2.x. Would you please explain how is it possible in QGIS 3.x

Comment: I don't use r. I only mention QGIS 3 as it does support multiple outputs.

Comment: @Luke Do you mean w.r.t python scripts? I mean supporting multiple outputs can only be w.r.t. some script, what else is the meaning of 'supporting multiple outputs'. I am really new to QGIS so can't get you.

Comment: Yes, setting multiple outputs as a single parameter w.r.t QGIS Processing python scripts.

Comment: Do you see any error message? The first syntax (multiple output raster) works for me.

Comment: @Kazuhito Yes, I see an error. It is actually not going to work in 2.x as mentioned by Luke in the first comment. What version do you have?

Comment: @MadhurPanwar I use QGIS 2.18.21.  I do not know if QGIS 3 supports rsx.

Comment: @Kazuhito Please share the exact header which lets you output multiple raster. Neither `##out_ras = output multiple raster` nor  `##out_ras = multiple output raster` worked for me.

Comment: @MadhurPanwar Sure, but it is almost same as your first one `##out_plot_raster_1 = output raster`. Only difference is that you have a space left-side of equal sign. I write it `##out_plot_raster_1= output raster`. Without a space between `1` and `=`.

Comment: @MadhurPanwar I will post a script I use for a while. (Will delete it later, as it is not intended as an answer). Please try it and see if it gives you an error.

Comment: @Kazuhito What you suggested is to output a single raster layer and it perfectly works. What I want instead is to be able to output multiple raster layers all by one single variable. I thought this would be possible since we can input multiple layers by `##inp_ras = multiple raster`. The `multiple` is crucial here. It however turns out that this is not possible at all with 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set a common extent (ie., maximum extent of all polygons) and structure your R script so it creates a stack or brick object and adds each polygon result to the stack. In this way you only have to worry about outputting a single object representing all of the polygons.

Comment: Would you please elaborate? I do not know what an extent is and also how does making a single object solve the problem. How do I output that? Do you mean to say that I should make a single raster (of smallest rectangular size such that it covers all polygons, where in place of selected polygons, I classify oil/water while the other non-polygon area is left blank) and just output that raster?

Comment: For anyone who happens to come here for an answer:                                       This is the only workaround if you use 2.x (which you have to if you are using R since it is not yet supported in 3.x). I ended up doing what this answer suggests i.e. considering the smallest rectangle encompassing all the polygons as a single output raster.

Comment: @MadhurPanwar, if you need a raster for each polygon you can write a series of rasters and store them as a stack or brick object. This object can then be written out to a format such as tiff or img, which can support multiband rasters. In this way each polygon can have its own raster. The one caveat is that the dimensions of the rasters have to match including: origin and bounding coordinates, cell resolution, number of row and columns (which defines the extent). With a multiband stack/brick, you then have a single raster object to write to disk.

Comment: Thanks. Actually it turned out that the solution mentioned in the answer was more apt for what I wanted. Your input about 'brick' being written as a multiband raster is really great though. That's a really nice alternative.